# addButton not working a second time

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

Here's the scenario: We're developing a CMS-like tool, to manage the copy for various email campaigns. There's a form which allows the user to select a template to work from, and among other things, a tinymce editor (v4.1.6).
To support wildcards, buttons are being used to get values to populate a drop-down menu in tinymce. This all works just fine the first time around, but the moment the user selects a new template (which changes the form somewhat, an empty button is being rendered where the menu should be.

I've stepped through the code, looking at the variables values every step of the way, only to find that every variable holds the values I'd expect them to hold, and every function is being called when and where I need it to be called. I can't, for the life of me, work out why I'm not getting the same results the second time around `tinymce.init()` is being called. Anyway, here's the code, it's part of a fairly large module, but the `tinyInit` function is pretty self-contained:

```
var tinyInit = (function()
{
    var i,menu =[],
        cbContainer = {
            editor: false,
            cb: function () {
                cbContainer.editor.execCommand(
                    'mceInsertContent',
                    false,
                    this._value
                );
            }
        };
    return function (btns)
    {
        var config = {
            selector: 'textarea',
            setup: function (editor) {
                cbContainer.editor = editor;
                editor.addButton('button', {
                    type: 'menubutton',
                    text: 'Placeholders',
                    name: 'placeholders',
                    icon: false,
                    menu: menu
                });
            },
            toolbar: " button "
        };
        for (i=0;i<tinymce.editors.length;++i) {
            //or tinymce.editors[i].remove();
            tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, tinymce.editors[i].remove());
        }
        cbContainer.editor = false;
        btns = btns || $('.placeholders');
        for (i = 0, menu.splice(0, menu.length); i < btns.length; ++i) {
            menu.push(
                {
                    text: btns[i].textContent,
                    value: btns[i].value,
                    onclick: cbContainer.cb
                }
            );
        }
        (btns instanceof $ ? btns : $(btns)).remove();
        if (SomeGlobalModule.viewSource) {
            config.plugins = 'code';
        }
        tinymce.init(config);
    };
}());
```

Initially, the form might look something like this:

```
<textarea>Foobar</textarea>
<button class="placeholders" value="%NAME%">Name</button>
<button class="placeholders" value="%DATE%">Date</button>
```

Which works brilliantly: The textarea becomes a tinymce editor, and there will be a menu that allows the user to select the placeholders of choice, inserting them into the content neatly. However, when a new template is selected, and the entire form is reloaded (AJAX), I call this function from the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: SomeGlobalModule.url,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(r)
    {
        //frm variable is updated elsewhere, but it's updated correct & reliably
        frm.replaceWith($(r));//replace form, frm references current element
        reinitMenus();
        tinyInit($('.placeholders'));//reinit tinymce
    }
});
```

Again, all of the functions (*including the `setup` callback*) are being called, and the `menu` variable has the expected values throughout. Why, then, isn't the drop-down being populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update:*
The solution listed below still is the only way I got this placeholder menu business to work. Meanwhile, though, I have found the time to write a TinyMCE plugin, which I've put up [on github](https://github.com/EVODelavega/placeholder-plugin).
Because I've found evidence of people trying to do the same thing as I did, and each time the answer turned out to be writing your own custom plugin, I've decided to create a pull request to ask the maintainers of TinyMCE to provide this plugin themselves. If you happen to stumble on this question/answer, and want to see this plugin be included in TinyMCE [make some noise](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/pull/461).

I've found some time to actually look at the problem once more. I decided to create an actual plugin instead of adding the button/menu using the `setup` callback. To make my life easier, I've decided to add the plugin to the manager in my `tinyInit` function, constructing the `menu` array same as before. The code now looks like this:

```
var tinyInit = (function()
{
    var i,menu =[],
        cbContainer = {
            editor: false,
            cb: function () {
                tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand(
                    'mceInsertContent',
                    false,
                    this._value
                );
            }
        };
    return function (btns)
    {
        var config = {
            selector: 'textarea',
            plugins: ['placeholders'],
            toolbar1: "placeholders"
        };
        for (i=0;i<tinymce.editors.length;++i) {
            //or tinymce.editors[i].remove();
            tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, tinymce.editors[i].remove());
        }
        cbContainer.editor = false;
        btns = btns || $('.placeholders');
        for (i = 0, menu.splice(0, menu.length); i < btns.length; ++i) {
            menu.push(
                {
                    text: btns[i].textContent,
                    value: btns[i].value,
                    onclick: cbContainer.cb
                }
            );
        }
        tinymce.PluginManager.add('placeholders', function(editor) {
            editor.addButton('placeholders', {
                text: 'Placeholders',
                type: 'menubutton',
                name: 'placeholders',
                icon: false,
                menu: menu
            });
        });
        (btns instanceof $ ? btns : $(btns)).remove();
        if (SomeGlobalModule.viewSource) {
            config.plugins = 'code';
        }
        tinymce.init(config);
    };
}());
```

I'll probably look into a way to create this as a stand-alone plugin, and provide several methods to set the contents of the menu on the fly (ajax request, passing a menu array to the `init` call etc...). Meanwhile, this approach seems to work just fine. I'll leave it here in case somebody else ever encounters the same issues as I have.